# Custom node tpl being ignored

Tags: nodes

I have created a content type called 'Home' and I also create a new file called, node-home.tpl.php.

What I understood from the drupal documentation, that when a Node has the content type it should use node-contenttypename.tpl.php as the node template file, if it exists.

But mine isen't working and its defaulting back to node.tp.php.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file has to be called node--home.tpl.php.
There always has to be 2 '-' between type and name.

Comment: Great thanks! I read it here: https://drupal.org/node/17565, which I can only assume is for an older version.

Comment: Yes this one is for d6 and lower ;)